# How to center heading horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image: header]
[image: logo]

I have the following header in my website, I want to center the text both horizontally and vertically.
I am using class 'text-center' in bootstrap 4.  It works, however, it centers it in the space after the logo.  I want the text to to be centered relative to the header as a whole.  The following is the HTML and css code for the header.

```css
.header {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
padding-top: 0px;
background-color: #5186a7;
overflow: hidden;
}
.logo  {
display: block;
float: right; 
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;

}
```

```html
  <div class="header-sec">

        <div class="header">

        <a href="visitor_home.php">        
             <img src="images/header_logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">            
           </a>
           <h1 class="text-center"style="color:white;"><strong>خــدمـــة الــدراســات والأبــحــاث</strong></h1> 

           <div class="clr"></div>

        </div>
```

Comment: You can easily accomplish this if you make the logo a background image.

Comment: @DanMullin The logo is an anchor tag because I need to be able to click it to take me to the home page, so I can't make it a background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted ?

```css
.header {
height: 100px;
background-color: #5186a7;

display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

position: relative;
}
.logo  {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
right: 2rem;
width: 213px; 
height:82px
}
```

```html
  <div class="header-sec">

        <div class="header">

        <a href="visitor_home.php">        
             <img src="images/header_logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">            
           </a>
           <h1 class="text-center"style="color:white;"><strong>خــدمـــة الــدراســات والأبــحــاث</strong></h1> 

           <div class="clr"></div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted, however now the header became smaller and only half of the logo shows.

Comment: Smaller in height or width ? What is the size of your logo ?

Comment: Smaller in height.  Width: 213px , Height:82px.

Comment: I updated the answer but this will need a media query to be responsive proof

Comment: It worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my example, the inscription is strictly centered (flex) due to the absolute positioning of the logo.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-top: 0px;
  background-color: #5186a7;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.logo  {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  float: right; 
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-sec">

        <div class="header">

        <a href="visitor_home.php">        
             <img src="images/header_logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">            
           </a>
           <h1 class="text-center"style="color:white;"><strong>خــدمـــة الــدراســات والأبــحــاث</strong></h1> 

           <div class="clr"></div>

        </div>
```

Comment: It works, however, now the header became smaller and only half of the logo shows

Comment: I can figure out the size, but I don't know what size the logo itself is. Where can I see it and apply it in my answer? I can redo my decision. ... and the logo should also be in the center of the vertical?

Comment: I edited the question and attached the logo.  It's right beneath the first picture, it's all white though, so it might not be visible.  The size of the logo: Width: 213px , Height: 82px.  Yes the logo should also be vertically centered.

Answer (score -1):

Use `display: flex` property along with `justify-content` and `align-items` like the snippet below:

```css
.header {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
padding-top: 0px;
background-color: #5186a7;
overflow: hidden;
}
.logo  {
display: block;
float: right; 
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
}
.text-center {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-sec">
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="text-center"style="color:white;">
            <strong>خــدمـــة الــدراســات والأبــحــاث</strong>
        </h1> 
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this doesn't work

Comment: Isn't the text centered horizontally and vertically around the blue box?